# Handling the following use case in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I've been given the task of modelling a simple in Cassandra. Coming from an almost solely SQL background, though, I'm having a bit of trouble figuring it out.

Basically, we have a list of feeds that we're listening to that update periodically. This can be in RSS, JSON, ATOM, XML, etc (depending on the feed).

What we want to do is periodically check for new items in each feed, convert the data into a few formats (i.e. JSON and RSS) and store that in a Cassandra store.

So, in an RBDMS, the structure would be something akin to:

```
Feed:
feedId
name
URL

FeedItem:
feedItemId
feedId
title
json
rss
created_time
```

I'm confused as to how to model that data in Cassandra to facilitate simple things such as getting x amount of items for a specific feed in descending created order (which is probably the most common query).

I've heard of one strategy that mentions having a composite key storing, in this example, the the created_time as a time-based UUID with the feed item ID but I'm still a little confused.

For example, lets say I have a series of rows whose key is basically the feedId. Inside each row, I store a range of columns as mentioned above. The question is, where does the actual data go (i.e. JSON, RSS, title)? Would I have to store all the data for that 'record' as the column value?

I think I'm confusing wide rows and narrow (short?) rows as I like the idea of the composite key but I also want to store other data with each record and I'm not sure how to meld the two together...

Answer (score 1):

You can store everything in one column family.  However If the data for each FeedItem is very large, you can split the data for each FeedItem into another column family.

For example, you can have 1 column familyfor Feed, and the columns of that key are FeedItem ids, something like,

```
Feeds  # column family
   FeedId1  #key
      time-stamp-1-feed-item-id1   #columns have no value, or values are enough info
      time-stamp-2-feed-item-id2   #to show summary info in a results list
```

The Feeds column allows you to quickly get the last N items from a feed, but querying for the last N items of a Feed doesn't require fetching all the data for each FeedItem, either nothing is fetched, or just a summary.

Then you can use another column family to store the actual FeedItem data,

```
FeedItems # column family 
    feed-item-id1 # key
        rss   # 1 column for each field of a FeedItem
        title # 
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CQL should be easier to understand to you as per your SQL background.

Cassandra (and NoSQL in general) is very fast and you don't have real benefits from using a related table for feeds, and anyway you will not be capable of doing JOINs. Obviously you can still create two tables if that's comfortable for you, but you will have to manage linking data inside your application code.

You can use something like:

```
CREATE TABLE FeedItem (
  feedItemId ascii PRIMARY KEY,
  feedId ascii,
  feedName ascii,
  feedURL ascii,
  title ascii,
  json ascii,
  rss ascii,
  created_time ascii );
```

Here I used ascii fields for everything. You can choose to use different data types for feedItemId or created_time, and available data types can be found [here](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/cql_data_types), and depending on which languages and client you are using it can be transparent or require some more work to make them works.

You may want to add some secondary indexes. For example, if you want to search for feeds items from a specific feedId, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM FeedItem where feedId = '123';
```

To create the index:

```
CREATE INDEX FeedItem_feedId ON FeedItem (feedId);
```

Sorting / Ordering, alas, it's not something easy in Cassandra. Maybe reading [here](http://ayogo.com/blog/sorting-in-cassandra/) and [here](http://brianoneill.blogspot.it/2012/03/cassandra-indexing-good-bad-and-ugly.html) can give you some clues where to start looking for, and also that's really depending on the cassandra version you're going to use.